# Request failed with status code 404 (React Native, Axios)

Tags: react-native, expo, http-status-code-404

Good morning.

I have this [API](https://almodovar-98fa1-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/.json).

I'm trying to use it in my React Native project like this:

```
​// api.js
 import axios from "axios";
      
 const api = axios.create({
   baseURL: "https//almodovar-98fa1-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/",  
});


  // App.js    
  import api from "./services/api";

  import Filmes from "./components/Filmes";

  export default function App() {
  
  const [filmes, setFilmes] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
   async function loadFilmes() {
   try {
    const response = await api.get("/.json");
  
    setFilmes(response.data);
    console.log(response);
   
   } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
}
loadFilmes();
}, []);

  
 return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.textH1}>Almodovar Cult 
    Movie List</Text>
    <FlatList
      data={filmes}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <Filmes data= 
      {item} />}
    />
   </View>
   );
 }


// Filmes/index.js
   

import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

const Filmes = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>...</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Filmes;
```

But "I'm getting this error (Expo web) **Error: Request failed with status code 404**

I know this error means "can't be found". What am I doing wrong?

I tried

```
const response = await api.get("/.json");
const newArr = [];
        Object.values(response.data).map(key, (index) => {
          newArr.push(response.data[key]);
        });

setFilmes(newArr)
```

and it didn't work.

If I try to run this app via Expo on the android device, the error is **Network Error**

I already use this api [here](https://almodovarcultmovielist.netlify.app/).

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change you api.js file like this

```
import axios from "axios";

export default function Api(type, serviceUrl, params) {
  const baseURL = "https//almodovar-98fa1-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/";
  let url = baseURL + serviceUrl;

  axios.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json";
  axios.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = "application/json";

  switch (type) {
    case "get":
      return axios
        .get(url, { params: params })
        .then((response) => {
          return response;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          return error;
        });
    case "post":
      return axios
        .post(url, { params: params })
        .then((response) => {
          return response;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          return error;
        });
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

and call api from App.js like this

```
const response = await api("get",".json");
```

Comment: I also think author need remove slash from `const response = await api.get("/.json");`

Comment: Yes because baseURL already containg that slash like in mentioned api, that's why i removed it in answer

Comment: Thank you both for your help. The error indeed disappeared both on web and on device, but I still get this error on console: GET http://localhost:19006/https//almodovar-98fa1-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/.json 404 (Not Found) and I can't render anything because I got console.log(response.data) "undefined" as result.